# How to create page template in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I want to make a custom page template in wordpress to customized all section for a specific page. In my fully custom made theme using bootstrap.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please first to know how to ask good question in so and keep in mind **we are not code writing services** So I request to you please solve your problem first then if you are getting any error or mismatch then ask here we will happily help you

Comment: Wordpress does a great job of documenting this. Heck, a simple google search would afford you many many many opportunities to get your answer. Voted as too broad and not code related

Comment: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please try to google first, if you may not find anything. Then ask here. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file in your theme folder page-templatename.php

```
<?php
/**

 * Template Name: templatename

 */

 get_header(); ?>
```

and place this code in your created php file. Now you can found the page templte in your wordpress login.

Comment: Yeah this code is working thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link [wordpress from scratch](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/)

and also this one [codex wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

and also it is a good idea to copy wordpress twentyfifteen theme and use the theme structure for your custom wordpress theme

Comment: Good referencing websites thanks!