# How to add header and footer to html static page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have wordpress website that I have converted to html.

I only need one page from it.

I added this page to the directory of the second wordpress website.
test.com/html-page

My problem is: I want to add header and footer of the second website in it.

I have deleted the header and the footer of the html page and change it to php then added header and footer like this

code:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <!-- here is the page content-->
    </html>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But it doesn't show anything at all

Comment: what is get_header() and get_footer()?

Comment: Why would you want footer code outside the closing `</html>` tag?

Comment: @DCR I'm trying to call the header and the footer from my wordpress website

Comment: _"I added this page to the directory of the second wordpress website"_ What do you mean by "added?" Did you create a page in Wordpress? Is your PHP code in the Wordpress page template (probably right) or in the Wordpress content (probably wrong). Did you upload the file via FTP? Something else?

Comment: @kmoser I added the page via FTP, test.com/html-page/index.php

Comment: @kmoser"Is your PHP code in the Wordpress page template" can you please explain more?

Comment: That's not how Wordpress works. You have to create a page in the Wordpress dashboard, and specify which [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415050/how-to-create-page-template-in-wordpress) you want to use. The template can contain PHP.

Comment: You cannot add PHP code to a Wordpress page by pasting it into the Wordpress editor (unless you are using a plugin that allows it). Your PHP must go in the Wordpress template file that is used by the page.

Comment: @kmoser I tried this method, but the problem is becuse the website is converted from wordpress to static html it shows inisde that page missed up, so I'm trying to find other siliotion. I'm adding the code via FTP not wordpress editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
```

replace the "includes/header.php" with the php file you actually want